# Is there an expression similar to "at the wheel" to use when someone is flying a helicopter?

Tags: expressions, idiomatic-language

When someone is driving a car you can say that they're at the wheel.

Is there an expression similar to that to use when someone is flying a helicopter?

Answer (score 1):

You can say "In the pilot's seat" or "At the controls".  The expression "at the helm" really applies to boats, but would be understood for aircraft too, or just say "at the wheel" (which is understood to be figurative).  I suppose "at the yoke" would be understood too.

Comment: An aviation buff or someone with experience of helicopters, whose audience was likewise, might say 'at the collective'.